# Как правильно добавить элементы списка в таблицу Word?

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

Есть список названий продукции mists, элементы которого надо вбить в каждую строку 2 колонки таблицы в ворде. 
Сам список mists выглядит так ['"Манжета \ 380... "', '"Кольцо \ ... "', и т.д.]

Написал такой гавнокод:

`for mist in mists:
    for row in range(len_of_future_tables+1):
        for col in range(2):
                if row == 0:
                    row += 1
                    continue
                cell = passport_table.cell(row, col)
        cell.text = (mist)`

Вот пример как должно быть:

[image: Как должно быть]

Вот как оно получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается оно перебирает каждый элемент к каждой строке в колонке и когда уже элементы закончились, то остается последний элемент...

Как сделать так чтоб первый элемент списка сохранился в первой строке, второй во второй и т.д.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется у вас должно быть как-то так:

```
for row, mist in zip(range(1, len_of_future_tables+1), mists):
    cell = passport_table.cell(row, 1)
    cell.text = (mist)
```

Вам ведь надо перебирать строки и элементы списка параллельно, а для этого в Питоне есть функция `zip`. И перебирать нулевую строку вам не надо, я так понимаю, поэтому лучше сразу начать итерироваться с 1, а не с 0 в `range`.
А цикл по колонкам вообще не нужен, из него у вас используется только последнее значение итерации.
В вашем первоначальном варианте просто получается, что вы для каждого элемента списка заново проходите все строки и столбцы и записываете туда текущий элемент списка. Понятно, что после окончания списка во всех ячейках остаётся только последний элемент списка.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, 2 дня мучался, перечитал всю документацию по спискам... Не знал про зип! Благодарю. Получилось!